# How to determine function output type based on template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

The following construct is a minimal example of what I try to achieve: let the return type of a templated function depend on the input types. First I wrote (below a selection of a set that also specializes for `std::complex<>` variants):

```
template<class U, class V> struct result_type                { using type = U; };
template<>                 struct result_type<float, double> { using type = double; };
template<>                 struct result_type<double, float> { using type = double; };
```

Normally you could somewhere use in code:

```
template<typename U, typename V>
void function()
{ 
    using R = typename result_type<U, V>::type;
    ...
}
```

But in my case I need the construct:

```
template<typename U, typename V>
R function()  // Determine 'R' by result_type<U, V>::type
{         
    ...
}
```

I cannot find the right code to do this. Can this be done anyway?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're not happy with something like: `result_type<U, V>::type function();` or `auto function() -> result_type<U, V>::type;`?

Comment: Yes, works! Thanks, see my comment below the answer of Ted Lyngmo.

Comment: @JerryCoffin `auto` return type does not work in function *declarations*. And while uncommon, you can in fact forward-declare templated functions in header files and have the definition in source files, using explicit template instantiation. But if you have the definition in a header file, I would indeed just use `auto` for the return type.

Comment: @G.Sliepen: That depends. As used here (with a trailing return type) it most certainly does work (well, I did accidentally omit "typename", but with proper syntax, elsewhere, `auto` can work fine in this case). The place it doesn't work is when you don't specify a return type at all, as in: `auto foo(auto a, auto b) { return a + b; }`, so the compiler needs the body of the function to deduce the return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to use your type trait to define the return type of the function:

```cpp
template<typename U, typename V>
typename result_type<U, V>::type function()
{         
    // return {}; // ...
}
```

A possible simplification could be to make use of [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type):

```cpp
template<typename U, typename V>
std::common_type_t<U, V> function() {
    // return {}; // ...
}
```

Comment: Stupid mistake of me, things didn't compile because of an obvious error I made... I now see I can even do `template<typename U, typename V, typename R = result_type<U, V>::type>
R function(U u, V v){}` which is nice if `R` occurs multiple times in the code. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @JeroenBoschma You're welcome! Yes, that's another way - but that adds a template parameter to the function template that a user can "override" by explicitly specifying it. If that's not wanted, I'd try to avoid it. Simply do a `using R = ...;` inside the function if it's going to be used many times in there.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do but you can also select template functions using std::enable_if_t (SFINAE). Without the need for helper structs.
You can then also use functions from traits to be a bit more expressive. [std::enable_if_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)
If you can use C++20's concepts the syntax becomes even cleaner.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>

// you can also use SFINAE to select the correct overload for your function
template<typename U, typename V>
auto fn( U v1, V v2 ) -> 
    std::enable_if_t
    <
        std::is_floating_point_v<U> && 
        std::is_floating_point_v<V>, 
        double
    >
{
    return static_cast<double>(v1) + static_cast<double>(v2);
}

// or with C++20 concepts 
auto fn_cpp20(std::floating_point auto v1, std::floating_point auto v2)
{
    return static_cast<double>(v1) + static_cast<double>(v2);
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<double, traits::retval_t<float, float>>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<double, decltype(fn(1.0f,2.0))>);

    auto sum = fn(1.0f, 2.0);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<double, decltype(sum)>);

    auto sum2 = fn_cpp20(1.0f, 2.0);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<double, decltype(sum2)>);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My case is more complicated as the output can be one of all 4 combinations of `float`/`double` with `std::complex`. You always cast to a `double` output however. I have to look at the cast issue also, a cast is needed to enable addition of `float` and `std::complex<double>` for example, but several compilers generate extra code even for redundant casts...

Comment: Geen probleem. Most of all it was to show this is also a possibility (where at least float/double are mapped onto the same check/predicate). I think the explicit cast may not be needed since enable_if_t already determines the correct return type.  But as long as you have unique predicates you can create multiple sfinead/concept versions (This technique is also useful if you want overloads for functions without implicit conversions on call).